# Referencing a certain section of a script

Tags: php

I am sending out a request to a site, which needs a returning URL. Once that returning URL is put in, I'd like to run this particular section of my code.

How do I do this?

I have tried the return URL as :

```
file.php?auth=true
```

and

```
if($_GET['auth'] == 'true') {
 Do Something
}
```

But the previous page appears to load.

Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: "No joy with it" isn't an error. What happens when you request the page that piece of code is on? Oh and don't do this, every user who can read an address bar can set the auth flag to true.

Comment: Does it always execute the code inside the if clause, or does it never execute it? Not sure, but try replacing the `==` by a `===`.

Comment: @CodeCaster how would you propose I pass the params?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing with $_GET['auth'], so I can't tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got syntax error on the first line

It should be

```
if($_GET['auth'] == 'true') {
```

but yes, this is correct way to do it